# Copy constructor elision for direct initialization when the argument is converted to the destination type

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17, copy-elision

This question is about the wording of the c++ standard.

All compilers, and I think this is what should be, elide the copy constructor for the initialization of the object `b` bellow ([assembly here](https://godbolt.org/z/d1CKiO)):

```
struct B;

struct A{
    operator B();
};

struct B{
    B(const B&);
    B(B&&);
};

void test(A a){
    B b(a);
}
```

But when I read the standard, I do not see why this elision shall happen (bold mine) [[dcl.init]/17.6.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2):

> Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, [...], constructors are considered.
>   The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]).
>   **The constructor so selected is called** to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s).
>   If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

It is specifically said that the constructor is called. But no compiler does it.

*I imagine I am missing something or not reading correctly the standard. How should I read the standard?*

---

This contrast with the previous and next paragraphs of the standard that specifically mandate copy elision [[dcl.init]/17.6.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1):

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, **the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object**.

and [dlc.init]/17.6.3:

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversions that can convert from the source type to the destination type [...]
>   The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; [...]
>   **The call is used to direct-initialize,** according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization.

Where the last sentence send me back to [dcl.init]/17.6.1 which would also implies the copy elision.

Comment: Seems equivalent to example of [copy_elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that all the examples on this page match [dcl.init]/17.6.1 and not the paragraph 17.6.2 that disturbs me.

Comment: You're expecting the compiler to convert the `a` object to a temporary `B` object, then copy that temporary object into `b` during the construction of `b`?  It uses `b` to store the return value from `a`'s conversion to `B`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This is what I read in the standard. According to my reading copy-elision should not happen.

Comment: If a conversion operator is selected, then the compilers backtrack and process `B b(a)` as if it were `B b(a.operator B());`  , and so the prvalue materialization rules (aka. guaranteed copy elision) mean there is only one construction of a `B`.   To spell it out, even though the argument `a` is an lvalue,  the compilers actually interpret the initialization rules as if it were the prvalue `a.operator B()` in this case.   I've previously tried to find supporting evidence for this behaviour in the standard and failed.

Comment: https://wg21.link/CWG2327

Answer (score 1):

@T.C. answered in a comment, this is core langugage issue [CWG2327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327).